# 14.04 to 16.04, startup problem

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, startup

After upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04, after the restart it switch from something that say "clean something" a black screen and the ubuntu loading, after 1 hour or something like that it switch to an endless ubuntu loading.

Comment: Try selecting advanced option in grub

Answer (score 0):

"clean something" is probably a message saying your hard disk is clean, ie no errors.

The easiest step (assuming you aren't an expert on grub) is to get boot repair. Instructions are [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/). Let us know how it works out.

Comment: i gonna try this out when i gonna have time, but is it normal that when i reinstall 14.04 there is no bug and it work perfectly fine ?

Comment: Boot-repair will attempt to fix your 16.04 upgrade. Reinstalling 14.04 over 16.04 is an entirely different question. Search the forums for that answer.